# Is it possible to edit properties with keyboard in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

Is it possible to edit properties with keyboard in Eclipse? Any know keys does either nothing or something random.

I want to:

1) jump between properties

2) edit properties

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can edit them through keyboard.

**Alt+Enter**

- Display the properties of the selected item
- Refresh the selected item
- Rename the selected item
- Revert to the last saved state

You can check out this [article](http://www.shortcutworld.com/en/win/Eclipse.html).